# modal viewcontroller UITextView child view of several textFields

Tags: uitextfield, uitextview, modalviewcontroller

when a user clicks on a textField, I push a modal view controller that contains a single UITextView. I would like the user to be able to enter text in that UITextView, dismiss the modal view with a save button and have that text appear in the original textField. This is not hard if there is only one textField.

However, I would like to do this with many textfields and only one modal UITextView view, is this possible? More specifically, is this possible without creating a subclass for each TextField pressed? How do I inidicate that the text entered in the UITextView is to only be stored in whatever textField was touched to push modal UITextView?

Many thanks.
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you wondering, you set a standard user default to each textField's is editing method. It took me a while to figure this one out.